# setStyleAttribute position fixed not working in ie 9 with google apps script

Tags: internet-explorer, google-apps-script

with google apps script using IE 9 image.setStyleAttribute("position", "fixed"); 
 is not working for me. It works fine in chrome and ff. any ideas?

The image is shown, but it moves when I scroll. Anyone got fixed to work on ie
 (fixed is not supported before version 7)

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('fixed pos');

var image = app.createImage("BMW_700_sport_BW_1.JPG");
image.setStyleAttribute("position", "fixed");
app.add(image);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('fixed pos').setStandardsMode(true);
```

Comment: wow - works, thanks. Down side is, many widgets are now the wrong size :(

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately standards mode is an all-or-nothing proposition.

Answer (score 0):

Try setAttribute instead, it should work in all browsers.
See this link for it's reference http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_setattribute.asp